# Sum of GCD and LCM

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

If $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ and $ab > 2$ show that:

$$\text{lcm}(a, b) + \gcd(a, b) \le ab + 1$$

Let the lcm be $l$ and let the gcd be $g$.

We have to show:

$$g + l \le ab + 1$$

I know that:

$$gl = ab > 2$$

WLOG, suppose $a > b$

I have seen that: $g \le b $ and $l \ge b$
But that doesnt help

Comment: The constraint $ab>2$ is completely unnecesary. This holds for $(a,b)=(1,1)$ and for $\{a,b\}=\{1,2\}$ too. I am assuming $0\not\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: Even if $0\in\mathbb N$ in your context, we would still have a stronger statement if $ab\ge 1$ instead of $ab>2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $gl = ab$, we have $$ab + 1 = gl + 1 = g + l + gl - g - l + 1 = g + l +(g - 1)(l - 1) \ge g + l.$$

Comment: The $ab>2$ constraint is completely unnecessary. The inequality holds without the constraint (assuming OP meant $0\not\in\mathbb N$) and your answer doesn't use it (again, assuming $0\not\in\mathbb N$).

Comment: Though it is necessary if we assume $0\in\mathbb N$. Peano axioms wikipedia page includes it and Natural number wikipedia page includes it as the common convention.

Comment: greatest common divisor is not well defined if you allow zero.

Comment: @Joffan $\gcd(a,b),a,b\in\mathbb N_{0}$ is not well defined iff $a=b=0$. $\gcd(a,0)=a,\forall a\in\mathbb N_{\ge 1}$. So it is defined if you allow at most one zero, just not two (when talking about $\gcd$ of two numbers).

Comment: I would say the opposite - it's only defined if both are zero, not if one is zero and one not.  For example, how could you say $\gcd(0,5)=5$ when zero does not divide $5$?

Comment: Instead of assumptions, it would probably be better if the OP would be edited to use $\mathbb{N}^+$ or $\mathbb{N}^0$.

Comment: @Joffan You're thinking about lowest common multiple, in which case $\text{lcm} (0,a)$ is undefined for any $a\in\mathbb N_0$. If you take the definition of divisility [that allows divisibility by $0$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor) (and which says $0\mid a\iff a=0$), then $\text{lcm}(0,0)=0$ and $\text{lcm}(0,a)$ is undefined $\forall a\in\mathbb N_{\ge 1}$, just like you say, except you've mistook $\text{lcm}$ with $\gcd$.